# Efficient way to serialize/de-serialize List of Objects to byte[] c#

Tags: c#, performance, serialization, arrays

I am looking for some processing/memory efficient and simple technique to serialize/deserialize a list of objects (like List to byte[] and vice-verse. I came to know that google uses protobuf for this and there are similar ports available for c#. I just need know the most efficient and simple way of serializing and de-serializing a list of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://stevenhollidge.blogspot.it/2011/07/comparing-protobuf-net-serialisation.html) you can find a serialization protocol comparison... basically here are the results:

[image: Serialization comparison]

Comment: please guide me if the code below is efficient and workable... `public static Stream SerializeUsingProtobuf(object pSource)
        {
            var model = CreateModel();
            using (Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                model.Serialize(memoryStream, pSource);
                return memoryStream;
            }
        }

        public static IList<Summary> DeSerializeUsingProtobuf(Stream pSource)
        {
            var model = CreateModel();
            return model.Deserialize(pSource, null, typeof(IList<Summary>)) as IList<Summary>;
        }`

Comment: It is not so easy to read your code (since comments do not allow proper formatting... it would be nicer if you could post a different question in this case!)... anyway your code *seems* good to me.

Comment: im getting error **"Duplicate field-number detected; 1"** on this statement `TypeModel compiled = model.Compile();`, any clue to fix it? i don't have any inherited types in my class, its just a POCO

Comment: Without having all the relevant code is heard to help you more... Anyway, I repeat: this is a brand new question with respect to your first post... so ask a new question.